Cannot use WeakReferenceMessenger inside MAUI windows
I tried to dynamically change the title bar color according to the user's selected theme in my MAUI Windows application. This is a MAUI multi-platform template, similar to Xamarin Forms. Finally, I added a ViewModel to App.xaml.cs inside the Windows project and attempted to change the color dynamically using MessagingCenter. this worked, but it has been deprecated. So I switched to WeakReferenceMessenger, but it is throwing an exception.
InnerException

{"Could not load file or assembly 'WinRT.Runtime, Version=2.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99ea127f02d97709'. The system cannot
find the file specified.":"WinRT.Runtime, Version=2.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99ea127f02d97709"}    System.Exception
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

Message

"The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception."   string


App.xaml.cs (Inside Windows project)
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace XX.WinUI;

public partial class App : MauiWinUIApplication
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLaunched(args);
        this.Resources["AppViewModel"] = new AppViewModel();
    }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}

ViewModel(Inside Windows project)
   public partial class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _titleBarColor;
        private string _titleColor;

        public string TitleBarColor
        {
            get => _titleBarColor;
            set
            {
                if (_titleBarColor != value)
                {
                    _titleBarColor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string TitleColor
        {
            get => _titleColor;
            set
            {
                if (_titleColor != value)
                {
                    _titleColor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public AppViewModel()
        {

            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<WeakReferenceMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
});
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


   public class WeakReferenceMessage : ValueChangedMessage<TitleBarModel>
   {
       public WeakReferenceMessage(TitleBarModel value) : base(value)
       {
       }
   }

(Inside Windows project)
This method is inside UWPPhoneFeatureService which is the native custom renderer.
public void ChangeDeviceStatusBarColor()
  {
      TitleBarModel titleBarModel = new TitleBarModel();
      string themeCode = GetAppSetting("ColorTheme");
      Windows.UI.Color col;
      switch (themeCode)
      {
          case "theme-black":
              col = ConvertColor(38, 33, 61);
              titleBarModel.TitleColor = "#FFFFFF";
              break;

          case "theme-monaco":
              col = ConvertColor(124, 147, 131);
              titleBarModel.TitleColor = "#FFFFFF";
              break;

          default:
              col = ConvertColor(1, 179, 239);
              titleBarModel.TitleColor = "#FFFFFF";
              break;
      }

      titleBarModel.TitleBarColor = AppSettingKey.statusBarColor = $"#{col.R:X2}{col.G:X2}{col.B:X2}";

      WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new WeakReferenceMessage(titleBarModel));
 
  }

Windows side
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseSharedMauiApp();
        builder.UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
        builder.UseMauiCameraView();
        builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
        {
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(FormsWebView), typeof(FormsWebViewRenderer));
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPhoneFeatureService, UWPPhoneFeatureService>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}


Try to add <WindowsAppSdkDeploymentManagerInitialize>false</WindowsAppSdkDeploymentManagerInitialize> in csproj. And what's the version of .NET, 7 or 8?

The version is .NET 8

I had the same problem. It seems like CommunityToolkit.Mvvm version 8.3.0 causes the issue. Try downgrading CommunityToolkit.Mvvm to 8.2.2. The 8.3.0 just came the same day you posted.

@BimTertulies check my answer and add the entry to get the app working with latest nuget.

According to the issue on github, you need to add the WindowsSdkPackageVersion entry to your csproj:
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.26100.42</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

Use the version that matches your TargetFramework in te csproj:
For Windows 10:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.19041.42</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

For Windows 11 22/23H2:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.42</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

For Windows 11 24H2:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.26100.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.26100.42</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>


Is it correct that this issues is solved by the 8.3.1 release of the community toolkit?

add the entries to be safe and test it. Look on nuget what is the latest version
